# Failed to initialize Monitor Thread

Tags: android, eclipse

As I opened my Eclipse i found this error in my logcat...dont know how to deal with it...Can Anyone explain this thing and overcome with a solution...I wud be very grateful..

Logcat:

```
 [2013-06-30 22:33:17 - ddms] Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection
[2013-06-30 22:33:22 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2013-06-30 22:33:26 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2013-06-30 22:33:28 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 2
[2013-06-30 22:33:30 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 3
[2013-06-30 22:33:32 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 4
[2013-06-30 22:33:34 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 5
[2013-06-30 22:33:37 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 6
[2013-06-30 22:33:39 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 7
[2013-06-30 22:33:41 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 8
[2013-06-30 22:33:43 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 9
[2013-06-30 22:33:45 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 10
[2013-06-30 22:33:47 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 11
[2013-06-30 22:33:50 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 12
[2013-06-30 22:33:52 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 13
[2013-06-30 22:33:55 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 14
[2013-06-30 22:33:57 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 15
[2013-06-30 22:34:00 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 16
[2013-06-30 22:34:02 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 17
[2013-06-30 22:34:05 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 18
[2013-06-30 22:34:07 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 19
[2013-06-30 22:34:10 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 20
[2013-06-30 22:34:12 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 21
[2013-06-30 22:34:15 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 22
```

Comment: I guess it's for the device that is connected to your laptop/pc. unplug it and plug it again or use other USB ports.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with DDMS connection and search google to no avail.

I happen to use COMODO Firewall, and fiddling around with the settings helped. In COMODO firewall 2013 (free edition), go to task button, advanced tasks > open advanced settings > expand the security settings menu > expand the firewall menu > firewall settings > uncheck "Filter loopback traffic (eg 127.x.x.x, :::1)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. I checked the Android SDK Manager and installed the required updates. It worked for me.

Steps:

1) Go to Android SDK Manager.

2) Expand the Android version that you will be using.

3) If you see updates available next to the Android version that you have selected, Make sure you install all the updates before starting your android virtual device

4) After all the required updates are installed, start your AVD

NOTE: Make sure to select the ARM option when selecting the Android OS version.

Answer (score 0):

eclipse can't connected to 127.0.0.1:... , you may be setup some software similar "windows firewall" and this software disable connect port for eclipse!